# How to create a Thread (Prime numbers and ArrayList)?

Tags: java, multithreading, list, arraylist

I have this code below, which creates 50 unique random number from 1 to 100 and adds it in an `ArrayList`.

Now I need a `Thread` (in a separate class) which checks the 50 unique random numbers if they are prime numbers (can only be divided by themself and 1.).

If a number in the List is not a prime number, it has to be removed from the list.

Unfortunatey I have no experience with Threads, can someone please help me?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class RandomPrim {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random nr = new Random();
        int number;
        ArrayList<Integer> liste = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // get 50 random unique numbers between 1 and 100
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= 50; ) {
            number = 1+nr.nextInt(100);

            if(!(liste.contains(number))) {
                liste.add(number);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("50 random unique numbers between 1 and 100: ");               
        for (int ausgabe : liste) {            
            System.out.print(ausgabe + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having no experience is not a valid reason to not **try** to do anything yourself. Basically you just dropped the essential part of your homework/learning effort ... on other people. What do you think you will learn from asking other people to do the heavy lifting for you? Hint: you start by reading tutorials on threading. Or books. There is really plenty of material out there!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questioner is not showing any evidence that he tried solving the problem on himself; he is merely dropping his requirements here.

Comment: I vote against closing it. The effort to learn should be encouraged, directed, guided, and not blocked. We all were, and still are beginners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Thread in a separate class can be achieved like this:

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {

    private List<Integer> myList;

    public MyClass(List<Integer> myList) {
        this.myList = myList; //Constructor for the class
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

You start the Thread like this:

```
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(); //Your list you want to check
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(myList);
    new Thread(myClass).start();
```